# Use Different MongoDB Collections For Different Merged Projects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, collections

I have 2 nodeJs projects that I recently merged into one nodeJs server while keeping the controllers, service and mongoDB models in separate folders for the two projects. The issue is, After merging the routs from two separate nodeJs servers to one, Both had their own separate collection in the database But I am unable to switch to a different collection for the different routes. I want to have the Ratings object in one project folder be calling a different database collection than the ratings in the other. I call the database helper for a connection but cannot use mongoose.connect twice.

I tried `mongoose.connection.useDb('squareCollection');` while commenting the connect part but that didnt work. If i try replacing the mongoose.connection() to mongoose.createConnection() on both projects, I get a error: `Operation squareusers.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms`

how can I refactor my code to run different connections for the two different routes and servers since I moved the routes of one server to the other and they are just seperated from routes on the same server.

my db.js file is:

```
const config = require('config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || config.get('connectionString'), {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true}).then(()=>{})
    .catch(e=>console.log(e));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports = {
    SquareRating: require('../users/rating.model'),
    Image: require('../images/images.model'),
    ... //more models
};
```

my MongoDb Model in both projects are in the following structure:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    rating: { type: Number, unique: false, required: true },
    orgUuid: { type: String, required: true },
    note: { type: String, unique: false, required: false},
});

schema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('SquareRating', schema);
```

and I call the model in the service with the mongoDB connection as:

```
const db = require('../_helpers/db');
const Rating = db.Rating;
return  Rating.find({id: id});
```

the routes for the two different backends are in the server.js as:

```
app.use('/api/square/users', require('./project1-server-backend/users/users.controller'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./project2-server-backend/users/users.controller'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating multiple collections, you need to use `createConnection`. Please refer - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

Sample code for your use case -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.URI1);
const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.URI2);

conn1.model('SquareRating', require('path to SquareRating schema for connection 1'));
conn1.model('OtherModelOnConn1', require('path to another schema for connection 1'));

conn2.model('Image', require('path to Image schema for connection 2'));
conn1.model('OtherModelOnConn2', require('path to another schema for connection 2'));



module.exports = {
    conn1,
    conn2
};
```

Import conn1, conn2 based on requirement. Models should be registered on correct connection in order to get the correct result.